# Ajax request is working only once, the second time after first request code not working

Tags: jquery, ajax

I have an ajax request with the following code

```
jQuery("ul.catLists li a, .vd_item_content .videoList .videoItem .vd_item_info .video_desc .video_cat_name span").each(function(){          
    jQuery(this).click(function (e) {
        jQuery(".scrollable_cats").hide();
        $(this).parent().addClass("activeTab");         
        $(this).parent().siblings().removeClass("activeTab");
         $(this).parent().parent().parent().find('li.restcats ul li').removeClass("activeTab");
         $(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.music_part ul li').removeClass("activeTab");
        e.stopPropagation();                
        var termId = $(this).attr('id');                    
        var url = '/wp-admin/admin-ajax.php?action=get_current_terms&termId='+termId;               
        jQuery.ajax({               
            type: "get",                
            url: url,               
            success: function (data){                       
                jQuery('.vd_item_content').empty();             
                jQuery('.vd_item_content').append(data);
                jQuery('.vd_item_content').css({"padding-bottom":"200px"});
                jQuery('#dot1').dotdotdot({
                    wrap: 'letter'
                });
                jQuery("ul.videoList li:nth-child(5n)").css({"margin-right":"0px"});
                jQuery('.share_hover_icon').each(function(){
                    jQuery(this).hover( 
                        function() {
                            jQuery(this).parent().find('.social_shareonhover').show();
                            jQuery(this).parent().find('.social_shareonhover').addClass("slideInLeft");
                        }, function() {
                             jQuery(this).parent().find('.social_shareonhover').hide();
                             jQuery(this).parent().find('.social_shareonhover').removeClass("slideInLeft");
                    });
                });

             jQuery('.videoImg').each(function(){
                jQuery(this).hover(
                    function() {
                        jQuery(this).parent().find('.hidden_overlay').show();
                      jQuery(this).parent().find('.hover_play').addClass("slideInRight");
                    }, function() {
                       jQuery(this).parent().find('.hidden_overlay').hide();
                         jQuery(this).parent().find('.hover_play').removeClass("slideInRight");
                });
            });           

            }               
        });             
        return false;           
    });     
});
```

After clicking on .vd_item_content .videoList .videoItem .vd_item_info .video_desc .video_cat_name span it loads posts items with this same .vd_item_content .videoList .videoItem .vd_item_info .video_desc .video_cat_name span with its id and that time when I click to .vd_item_content .videoList .videoItem .vd_item_info .video_desc .video_cat_name span code didnt work and do anything.Why it is working only once?

Comment: hi can you make jsfiddle for this.?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That is because you are emptying the parent container and adding the new data . and the click function is associated with older elements. you should rather use event delegation by attaching event to static parent element or body.

also you do not need to iterate over elements using `each()` and attach event individually. you can simply attach to the selector itself:

```
jQuery("body").on('click','ul.catLists li a, .vd_item_content .videoList .videoItem .vd_item_info .video_desc .video_cat_name span' , function (e) {
  //rest code............
}
```

Comment: how I can do some check and connect this clicked element id and top category filter id and add active class to following category? @Milind Anantwar

Comment: i am not sure what you mean by that. could you point to right place??

Comment: the click is in the post item that containes the category which belong to, at the top of this items I have a category filter.When clicking on the category within the post I need to add active class and some style to the filter also with the current category.I need to connect in some way .vd_item_content .videoList .videoItem .vd_item_info .video_desc .video_cat_name span id with ul.catLists li a id.Their id are the same with term id value.How I can do check and add class to current filter item?

Comment: I am trying with this code `if(jQuery(this).attr('id') === jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.catLists li a').attr('id')){
           jQuery(this).parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().parent().find('.catLists li a').addClass('oddclass'); 
        }` but it find and check only the first .catLists li a item, how I can through each one and find the matched one?

Comment: you can use something like `$('[termid='+this.id+']').addClass('active')`

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/86757/discussion-between-anahit-dev-and-milind-anantwar).

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
jQuery("ul.catLists li a, .vd_item_content .videoList .videoItem .vd_item_info .video_desc .video_cat_name span").each(function(){          
    jQuery(this).click(function (e) {
```

to

```
jQuery('body').on('click', 'ul.catLists li a, .vd_item_content .videoList .videoItem .vd_item_info .video_desc .video_cat_name span', function (e) {
 .................
 })
```